# How to extract values from complex list forms

Tags: python

I have a list
result_list=['hello(1,2)','bye(3,4)']

How to get a string

\>>hello

\>>1

\>>2

Comment: Have you tried / researched anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did not understand your question but i am trying to help you

i think you want the result be like this

1- the word that contains numbers

2- the numbers

i think this code will help:

```py
for i in result_list:
    print(i.split("(")[0])
    print(i.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0].split(",")[0])
    print(i.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0].split(",")[1])
```